# how to collapse horizontal using iron-collapse in polymer

Tags: polymer

how to using iron-collapse horizontal in polymer?

i have basic code like this :

```
<button on-click="toggle">toggle collapse</button>

<iron-collapse id="collapse" horizontal>
  <div>Content goes here...</div>
</iron-collapse>
```

i read this guide, and it's work but i'm 
confused to implements properties on this tutorial : [iron collapse](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-collapse)

how to implements collapse horizontal on iron collapse?

need help, thanks before :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configuring-boolean-properties), Boolean properties are set to `true` when present on the element. Otherwise, they default to `false`.

To set the `horizontal` property of `iron-collapse`, just add its name as an attribute to the tag like this:

```
<iron-collapse horizontal>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/webcomponents+webcomponents+:v0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      .collapse-content {
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        background-color: lightgray;
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <button on-click="toggle">Collapse</button>
      <iron-collapse id="collapse" opened horizontal>
        <div class="collapse-content">
          <div>Content goes here...</div>
        </div>
      </iron-collapse>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          toggle: function() {
            this.$.collapse.toggle();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vKEvMV?editors=1000)</sup>